# what is the difference between replace, replaceAll and replaceAllLiterally in scala?

Tags: scala, replace, replaceall

what is the difference between `replace`, `replaceAll` and `replaceAllLiterally` in Scala or Java?

Answer (score 1):

`replace` and `replaceAllLiterally` are similar, and in fact the latter is deprecated. From [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/StringOps.html#:%7E:text=returned%20by%20linesWithSeparators.-,%EE%85%97,-def):

> (Since version 2.13.2) Use s.replace as an exact replacement

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) on the other hand matches the string with regex and replaces it with the replacement string.